# Set a variable in python according to given JS source

Tags: javascript, python, html, parsing

I have a piece of JS source code, that contains some functions and a global variable, something like:

```
** some js code **

data = [
         [1, 2, 3, '1.000'],
         [1, 3, 3, '2.000']
]

** some other js code **
```

I need to work with the content inside the data variable, but I don't know Javascript and I would strongly prefer to use numpy to work with that data.
Basically I need to convert that data variable from JS source to python.

The bigger picture here is - I actually have a .html file that I just pull to the same folder as the python script. The HTML file has all the HTML and this piece of javascript. I suppose I will be able to parse this JS out from html using something like BeatifulSoup, but I don't know how to work the JS. If you would have a completely different solution, I would welcome it.

Comment: If I were you I would slightly modify the JS file to output the data you need in JSON format. Using something like `console.log(JSON.stringify(data)` see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify then once you have your JSON string, you can parse that into Python data (dicts, arrays etc, however it comes out) using Python's JSON module https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Comment: Thank you, but this sort of eliminates the meaning of why Im doing this. Right now, I just copy it from the javascript source to my python code. But the variable has gotten quite big and now it takes almost a minute to copy it all. I was hoping I could always just save the html file from the website and then do this in a more automated way. I was hoping that I could download the file through requests library, but you need to be logged to the website and it has no public sort of API and I simply don't know how to log in through python script and download the page.

Comment: Oh actually, I can do this through chrome console right? And it has the copy option. That looks nice. That may work.

Comment: If that `data` variable is in global scope, that is to say not placed inside any function calls or anything like that. You should be able to run `JSON.stringify(data)' in the dev tools console, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was lucky and was able to parse out the whole part through finding a substring within the html page, since there were only the desired matches.

Basically the code looked something like this:

```
<script>
*** some js code ***
data = [ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ....
        ....
     ];</script>
```

I had the whole page in a single string s and I was able to do

```
s.find("data = [")
```

which returned the desired position and then I used

```
s.find("];</script>")
```

which also returned the desired position.
Then I used those 2 integers returned from those 2 call finds to slice the string, so that I got only the part with desired data.

I am then able to call exec(s), eval(s) or asc.literal_eval(s) to evaluate the string, which creates the variable data with the exact contents.